# How to access mongodb as proxy in aws?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, mongodb-atlas

My situation is as follows.

1. MongoDB is configured and used in atlas.
2. mongoDB must be configured so that only allowed IPs can be accessed.
3. I need to access mongoDB from aws fargate.
4. However, since fargate does not have a fixed IP range, it is difficult to make inbound calls to external systems such as atlas.

- now
  Currently, mongoDB is accessed through NAT Gateway, but the cost has increased significantly due to other problems such as ECR load.
- todo
  So I'm trying to create a proxy-only ec2 and access mongoDB through it.
  I'm a little worried about adding one more thing to manage.

Is there any better way than this?

Comment: If ECR pulls are the only reason your NAT Gateway costs have increased, that can be solved by adding an ECR Gateway interface to your VPC.